Very low video quality in Zoom with 100% cpu usage
The video signal is great in my self-view when I open zoom or in the video settings preview.
But for other meeting guests the recording is very low quality.
The reason is the 100% CPU usage of the Zoom app. Does anyone have a solution?
My system:

Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Logitech C920 Webcam
Zoom Version: 5.17.11 (3835)
Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)

